# Error al enviar los datos de arduino a mi servidor local

Tags: php, mysql, arduino

Tengo un prblema para enviar los datos de mi sensor a un servidor local, ya lo habia probado con un solo sensor y me funciono que fue el lm35, ahora que agrege otro sensor no logro enviar los datos, en arduino me dice que todo esta correcto aqui les dejo los codigos para que me ayuden a encontrar mi error

[BASE DE DATOS]

```
CREATE TABLE `variable` (
  `fecha` datetime NOT NULL,
  `valor` float NOT NULL,
  `rutax` float NOT NULL,
  `rutay` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

[CODIGO DE PHP]

```
<?php
$mysql_servidor = "localhost";
$mysql_base = "sensor";
$mysql_usuario = "root";
$mysql_clave = "";

$valor = htmlspecialchars($_GET["valor"],ENT_QUOTES);
$rutax  = htmlspecialchars($_GET["rutax"],ENT_QUOTES);
$rutay = htmlspecialchars($_GET["rutay"],ENT_QUOTES);

// Valida que esten presente todos los parametros
if (($valor!="") and ($rutax!="") and ($rutay!=""))

{
    mysql_connect($mysql_servidor,$mysql_usuario,$mysql_clave) or die("Imposible conectarse al servidor.");
    mysql_select_db($mysql_base) or die("Imposible abrir Base de datos");   
    $sql = "insert into variable (fecha, valor, rutax, rutay) values (NOW(),'$valor','$rutax','$rutay')";
    mysql_query($sql);

}
?>
```

[codigo de arduino]

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "MPU6050.h"
#include "Wire.h"
MPU6050 sensor;

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
EthernetClient client;
char server[] = "192.168.1.100";
unsigned long ultimaConexion = 0;
// Estado de la ultima conexion
boolean ultimoEstado = false;
const unsigned long intervaloConexion = 10000;
float tempC; // Temperatura en celsius
float acelx;
float acely;
int MPU6050 = 0;
int LM35 = 0;

int ax, ay, az;



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600); 
  sensor.initialize(); 
  Serial.println("Sensor de temperatura LM35");
  // Espera 1 segundo para que se inicie la tarjeta Ethernet
  Serial.println("Sensor de Acelerometro ");  
  delay(1000);
  Ethernet.begin(mac);
  // Imprime la direccion IP de la tarjeta
  Serial.print("Direccion IP: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}
// Loop principal
void loop() {
  // Lee la temperatura desde el sensor
  tempC = analogRead(LM35);

  // Convierte el valor leido a temperatura
  tempC = (5.0 * tempC * 100.0) / 1024.0;
  acelx = analogRead(MPU6050);
 acelx=atan(ax/sqrt(pow(ay,2) + pow(az,2)))*(180.0/3.14);
 acely = analogRead(MPU6050);
 acely=atan(ay/sqrt(pow(ax,2) + pow(az,2)))*(180.0/3.14);

 sensor.getAcceleration(&ax, &ay, &az);


  // Si hay datos que llegan por la conexion los envia a la puerta serial
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }


  if (!client.connected() && ultimoEstado) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("Desconectando...");
    client.stop();
  }

  if (!client.connected() && (millis() - ultimaConexion > intervaloConexion)) {
    httpRequest();
  }
  ultimoEstado = client.connected();
}
void httpRequest() {
  if (client.connect(server, 8080)) {
    // Envia el dato al puerto serial
    Serial.print("Sensor LM35: ");
    Serial.print(tempC);
    Serial.println(" grados Celsius");
  Serial.print("Sensor Acelerometro: ");

  Serial.print(acelx); 
   Serial.print("Inclinacion en X: ");
   Serial.println(acely);
  Serial.print("tInclinacion en Y:");

    // Envia el requerimiento al servidor via GET
    Serial.println("Iniciando conexion...");
    client.print("GET http://192.168.1.100:8080/ARDUINO/sensorarduino.php?valor=&rutax=&rutay=");
    client.print(tempC);
    client.print(acelx);
    client.print(acely);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.print("Host: ");
    client.println(server);
    client.println("User-Agent: Arduino-Ethernet");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();   
    ultimaConexion = millis();
  }
  else {

    Serial.println("Error al conectarse al servidor");
    Serial.println("Desconectando...");
    client.stop();
  }
}
```

[image: Ok]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Lado del servidor (PHP):

El código que muestras no tiene medidas de control de ejecución de las consultas SQL y no muestras nada en caso de que los parámetros sean incorrectos, por lo que si algo falla no sabes qué ha ocurrido.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo correctamente:

```
<?php
$mysql_servidor = "localhost";
$mysql_base = "sensor";
$mysql_usuario = "root";
$mysql_clave = "";

// Valida que estén presente todos los parámetros
if (
    !empty($_GET["valor"]) && !empty($_GET["rutax"]) && !empty($_GET["rutay"])
) {
    $valor = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["valor"]);
    $rutax = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["rutax"]);
    $rutay = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["rutay"]);
    mysql_connect($mysql_servidor, $mysql_usuario, $mysql_clave)
        or die("Imposible conectarse al servidor.");
    mysql_select_db($mysql_base)
        or die("Imposible abrir Base de datos");   
    $sql = "
        INSER INTO variable (
            fecha,
            valor,
            rutax,
            rutay
        ) values (
            NOW(),
            '$valor',
            '$rutax',
            '$rutay'
        )
    ";
    /* Guardamos el resultado de la ejecución de la consulta */
    $resultado = mysql_query($sql);
    /* Si ha fallado (devuelve "false") informamos del error */
    if ($resultado === false) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    die("Registros insertados: ". mysql_affected_rows());
}
die("Parámetros incorrectos");
?>
```

De esta manera no sólo aparecerá un mensaje informativo cuando falle la conexión al servidor MySQL o la selección de la base de datos, aparecerá información del registro insertado (si se pudo insertar), del caso en el que los parámetros no estén definidos y cualquier error que se genere en la consulta (clave duplicada, disco lleno, error de sintaxis, etc).

**Te recomiendo encarecidamente migrar tu código a [PDO/MySQL](http://php.net/pdo-mysql) o [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli).** Las funciones `mysql_*` están marcadas como obsoletas en PHP 5.5 y eliminadas definitivamente a partir de PHP 7.

---

## Lado del cliente (Arduino):

La petición HTTP está montada de manera incorrecta (gracias @Xerif por la pista). Las modificaciones que te propuse en el PHP detectarían el problema con el mensaje *"Parámetros incorrectos"*.

La primera línea de la petición HTTP que generas quedaría de la forma:

```
GET http://192.168.1.100:8080/ARDUINO/sensorarduino.php?valor=&rutax=&rutay=<tempC><acelx><acely> HTTP/1.1
```

Los campos `valor` y `rutax` se envían vacíos y el campo `rutay` recibe todos los números concatenados. El objetivo sería montar la petición así:

```
GET http://192.168.1.100:8080/ARDUINO/sensorarduino.php?valor=<tempC>&rutax=<acelx>&rutay=<acely> HTTP/1.1
```

Para montar la petición HTTP de manera correcta puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
void httpRequest() {
  if (client.connect(server, 8080)) {
    // Envia el dato al puerto serial
    Serial.print("Sensor LM35: ");
    Serial.print(tempC);
    Serial.println(" grados Celsius");
    Serial.println("Sensor Acelerometro:"); 
    Serial.print("Inclinacion en X: ");
    Serial.println(acelx);
    Serial.print("Inclinacion en Y: ");
    Serial.println(acely);

    // Envia el requerimiento al servidor via GET
    Serial.println("Iniciando conexion...");
    client.print("GET http://192.168.1.100:8080/ARDUINO/sensorarduino.php?valor=");
    client.print(tempC);
    client.print("&rutax=");
    client.print(acelx);
    client.print("&rutay=");
    client.print(acely);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: " + server);
    client.println("User-Agent: Arduino-Ethernet");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    ultimaConexion = millis();
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error al conectarse al servidor");
    Serial.println("Desconectando...");
    client.stop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Aun que esto es cierto, no serviría de mucho,  pues en ningún momento se muestra la respuesta producida por el servidor desde arduino.

Comment: Sí lo hace, tras el comentario `Si hay datos que llegan por la conexion los envia a la puerta serial`...

Comment: gracias pero ya lo habia resuelto me gusto tu forma de hacer las cosas, lo voy adaptar a esta manera: el error era el GET(client.print("GET http://192.168.1.100:8080/ARDUINO/sensorarduino.php?&valor=");
    client.print(tempC);
    client.print("&rutax=");
    client.print(acelx);
    client.print("&rutay=");
    client.print(acely);)

Comment: Exacto, he editado la respuesta para que queden más claras las modificaciones que te propongo separadas por el lado del servidor (PHP) y del cliente (Arduino). Un saludo y me alegra que hayas solucionado el problema :) PD: Recuerda reforzar el código PHP controlando cualquier posible error que pueda producirse y, además, no olvides migrar el código a PDO/mysqli.